# Autowired field is null in spring boot with akka framework application

Tags: java, spring-boot, akka

I started akka-springboot application.Here autowired is not worked in my service.

```
Persistence.java

public interface Persistence extends CrudRepository<message, String>{

}
```

workactor.java

```
    @Component
    @Scope("prototype")
    public class workActor extends UntypedActor {

    @Autowired
    private Persistence persistence;

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Object message) throws Exception {
    LOGGER.INFO("--->> " + persistence) // here i got null value
    }

}
```

Guide this issue

Comment: @Gangaraju this is not necessary for Spring Data interfaces.

Answer (score 0):

Spring scans packages to find Repository interfaces and then creates proxies for them.
I assume you try to autowire repository into your Persistence class, not to other java class.
In your case Spring apparently didn't found your Persistence interface, so double check your configuration.

If you provide more details we could help more.